# Windows Service import C++ unmanaged code

Tags: c#, c++

I have both windows service and C++ unmanaged code("External.DLL") that were built x86 and the windows service calls one of the "External.DLL" functions that writes/reads in registry.
When I start the service as an administrator the windows service crashes for timeout reason.
To troubleshoot the problem, I made a log file, I wrote an instruction of logging before the instruction of calling the external function and another one just after.
In the log file I have got the "Before" log message and not the "After", and there is not exception catched.
PS: I have a console application that can access and calls the External.DLL functions.
what can I do ? What can I add as configuration for windows service project ?

Comment: That's because Your service cannot interact with Windows Service Manager. Probably the problem is in your Start Service code or given a wrong permission.

Comment: @AliSepehri-Amin: I can see no relation between the question and your comment.

Comment: @K.chaa: Did you expect unmanaged C++ code to throw a managed .Net exception? How do you know the service "crashed"? Because the symptoms sound merely like it's nor responding, and you can get that from a simple `while(true) { }` infinite loop.

Comment: @MSalters I told him the reason of the crash.

Comment: @AliSepehri-Amin: Your comment is wrong. Start Service must have worked. We know this because the log file contains "Before".

Comment: "When I start the service as an administrator the windows service crashes for timeout reason." Could you please better explain this phrase? It means that the service doesn't crash if you don't start it as an administrator? If the service crash how do you know the reason is a timeout? Finally, please add some code to better understand the problem

Comment: Well, it is something unsubtle.  The C++ code doesn't just crash when you call it from your OnStart() method, it goes out in the woods and doesn't come back.  Without having any idea what it does, you of course can't get a decent guess why that might be.  You'll have to debug it, attach the unmanaged debugger to the service process.  Then Debug > Break All, Debug > Windows > Threads to ensure you have the right thread selected, the Call Stack should point at the evil-doer.

Comment: @HansPassant When I debugged the service, I stepped into the function and it doesn't come back.

Comment: Well, you already knew that, you'll have to find out *why* it doesn't come back.  It doesn't sound like you followed my advice, Debug > Break All is not scary.  You can only get a guess when you show us that call stack.

Comment: @SimoneCifani In this phrase i wanted to explain that there is no privileges issues. It doesn't really crash but it continues to try starting the process. In face this is how I imported the dll [DllImport("External.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int InitFunction(int int1, int int2, bool bDisplay, out int tagNumber);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the external function, an "afxMessageBox" was written in the beginning of the function. So it blocks the windows service start.